# Authentication in WebApi with AllowAnonymous attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented a JWT-based authentication by inheriting `DelegatingHandler` and adding the class as `configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new MyDelegatingHandler())`.

When implementing `DelegatingHandler`, I override `Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)`. The logic is simple there - I retrieve a token from `Authorization` header, check it's validity. If it is valid - I set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and `HttpContext.Current.User`, otherwise I return `new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`

Basically it looks like this (very simplified):

```
public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = GetTokenFromAuthorizeHeader(request);
        if (TokenIsValid(token)) {
           var principal = CreatePrincipal(token);
           Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
           HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
           return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        } else {
           // TODO: fix
           return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }
    }
}
```

Now this method is called even on WebApi method that has `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute with it. This is good because I want to set principal even if the method allows anonymous. But this logic fails if the supplied token in `Authorization` header is invalid.

User sends a request to resource with `[AllowAnonymous]` and with an invalid token in `Authorization` header, which should come through because the resourse allows anonymous, but my code checks authorization, find out that the token is invalid and sends `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`.

The fix would be to check where `// TODO: fix` is whether the resource the user is accessing allows anonymous or not, and only send `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` if it is not, but I can't figure out how to properly do this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 1. Authentication Filter

Use [Authentication Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters), which Web API 2 introduced. They perform just *authentication*, but say nothing about if user has access to a resource or not. Exactly what you need.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var token = GetTokenFromAuthorizeHeader(context.Request);
        if (TokenIsValid(token)) {
            var principal = CreatePrincipal(token);
            // Use context.Principal instead of Thread.CurrentPrincipal
            // and HttpContext.Current.User whenever.
            context.Principal = principal;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    // TODO: Implement remaining IAuthencitaionFilter members.
}
```

Apply this `JwtAuthenticationFilter` globally to perform authentication for all requests:

```
// httpConfig is an instance of HttpConfiguration
httpConfig.Filters.Add(new JwtAuthenticationFilter());
```

In this way user is authenticated if token is OK. But still all users have access to your API - even the ones with invalid token. Let's move further and protect it.

### 2. AuthorizeAttribute

[AuthorizeAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api#using-the-authorize-attribute) is what you need to restrict access to Web API from unauthenticated users. You can apply it globally by using the same approach as above:

```
httpConfig.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

The one who doesn't have valid token won't pass. Good. The last step is to allow access to some particular resources for users with invalid tokens.

### 3. AllowAnonymousAttribute

From now on `AllowAnonymousAttribute` should work. Basically `AuthorizeAttribute` just checks if resource is marked by `[AllowAnonymous]` and skips authorization in this case.

---

### Conclusion

Generally Web API is protected from unauthenticated users, but some resources can disable authorization by applying `[AllowAnonymous]`. `JwtAuthenticationFilter` we implemented above works in any case, so users with valid token will be always authenticated - even if a resource allows anonymous access.

Comment: Thanks for your response, my understanding is that the problem I had basically is coming from using `DelegatingHandler` instead of `IAuthenticationFilter` and if I switch to `IAuthenticationFilter` it should work, right? I cannot unfortunately test your solution right now, but I will get back to it in a couple of days

Comment: @Archeg, right. I see in tags that you are using Web API 2, so `Authentication Filters` are available. I am not sure if it's even possible to do via `Message Handlers`, since they process request before it reaches any `ApiController`. But even if it's possible, better to create your own `IAuthenticationFilter`.

Comment: @yuriy-oborozhnyi Any idea how can I access httpConfig instance in .net6? I am unable to find a way to do it Program.cs