# How to remove Jwt Token Authentication for a Web API method

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a question on Jwt token Authentication.

I have a method "GetUserData" in some API controller. I want to remove Jwt token Authentication for that particular "GetUserData" method.

I have tried applying "AllowAnonymous"  filter but its not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will need to implement a filter to allow AllowAnnonymous attribute to work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624153/1384539